# Best method to append variable value inside a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have the following python 3.8 code:

```
def main():
father_year = int(1988)
c_year = int(2020)
x = 3
f_female = str("female")
m_male = str("male")
while father_year < c_year:
    print(father_year + x)
    father_year += x
```

It outputs:
1991
1994
1997
2000
2003
2006
2009
2012
2015
2018
2021

Whats the best method to add female and male each time it add the number 3?

Wanted output:
1991 Female
1994 Male
1997 Female
2000 Male
2003 Female
2006 Male
2009 Female
2012 Male
2015 Female
2018 Male
2021 Female

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if`, `else` statement to do it.

If you want to print everything in same line then:

```
def main():
    father_year = int(1988)
    c_year = int(2020)
    x = 3
    f_female = str("female")
    m_male = str("male")
    while father_year < c_year:
        if father_year % 2 == 0:
            print(father_year + x, 'Female', end = ' ')
            father_year += x
        else:
            print(father_year + x, 'Male', end = ' ')
            father_year += x
main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
1991 Female 1994 Male 1997 Female 2000 Male 2003 Female 2006 Male 2009 Female 2012 Male 2015 Female 2018 Male 2021 Female
```

If you want them in different lines then remove `end = ' '`.